# Displaying dynamic column data veritcally

Tags: c#, html, razor

I'm trying to display column data vertically from a generic excel file upload. Problem is that the model needs to hold a relation to the header because *it is* generic, which is causing an issue in displaying the column data. How can I manipulate - or iterate - column data vertically instead of horizontally; preferably without CSS manipulation.

i.e.

**Current display**

| A header | B header | C Header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A Data | A Data | A Data |
| B Data | B Data | B Data |
| C Data | C Data | C Data |

**Expected display**

| A header | B header | C Header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A Data | B Data | C Data |
| A Data | B Data | C Data |
| A Data | B Data | C Data |

**Sample Model**

```
public class HeaderVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ColumnDataVM> ColumnData { get; set; }

}
```

**Sample Code Displaying Table**

```
<table id="previewTable" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @if (Model?.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var header in Model)
                        {
                            <th scope="col">@header.Name</th>
                        }
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model?.Count > 0)
                {
                    @foreach (var header in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            @foreach (var column in header.ColumnData)
                            {
                                <td>@column.Value</td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

**Update**

Thanks @Victor

```
 <table id="previewTable" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @if (Model?.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var header in Model)
                        {
                            <th id="@header.Name" scope="col">@header.Name</th>
                        }
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model?.Count > 0)
                {
                    @for (int row = 0; row < Model?.Count; row++)
                    {
                        @(maxRowCount = Math.Max(maxRowCount, Model.Headers[row].ColumnData.Count))

                        <tr>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                @if (row < item.ColumnData.Count)
                                {
                                    <td>@item.ColumnData[row].Value</td>
                                }

                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

Comment: In this case, you should use for loop, so, you could access col and row via index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var maxRowsCount = 0;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    maxRowsCount = Math.Max(maxRowsCount, item.ColumnData.Count);

    // Print header in razor
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}

for (int row = 0; row < maxRowsCount; row++)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        // Print row in razor
        if (row < item.ColumnData.Count)
        {
            var value = item.ColumnData[row];
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

If your items has all the same count, you don't need maxRowsCount, you can use the Count of one of them.